Odoo17 page duplication in product report
I am encountering an issue with Odoo 17 when generating a custom stock report.
When I select the report and click "Print," I have made modifications to the product report using Odoo Studio. The problem arises when using the t-foreach loop in the report template. While the loop works correctly, it results in duplicate pages. For instance, if I print 4 records, the PDF ends up with 4 pages instead of displaying all 4 records on a single page.
I’ve attached a screenshot to illustrate the issue:
photo of the problem
Could you please assist me with this? The task deadline is December 31st.
Thank you for your help!
I tried dynamic table in odoo17 but it didn't work + I also used the normal fields and still nothing works

can you show the code or the change you added?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
